# AT-Commands from ESP32 to Fanstel BC805M (nRF52805M) not working

Tags: serial-port, microcontroller, esp32, at-command, nrf52

I want to send a simple AT-Command like: `AT\r\n` from the ESP32 to the Fanstel BC805M (nRF52805M) breakout board. My goal is to get an answer.

Problem: The Esp32 does not get an answer from the BC805M.

## Setup

### Hardware

- The ESP32 is connected by usb cable to my Mac.
- The ESP32 connects to the BC805M by five cables -> 3V3->VDD, GND->GND, Rx->Tx, Tx->Rx, GPIO32(high)->GPIO04(P004). Rx and Tx from ESP32 are Serial2 (not the Serial0 of the programmer). The P004 pin from BC805M is set to high to enable "command-mode".

### Software

- The BC805M came already preloaded with The AT commands code.
- The ESP32 is flashed by a simple Serial2 write/read arduino code:

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

#define RXD2 16
#define TXD2 17
#define CMD_MODE 32

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial2.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);
  pinMode(CMD_MODE, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(CMD_MODE, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("start");
}
void loop() {
  Serial2.write("AT\r\n");
  delay(500);
  if(Serial2.available()){
    Serial.write(Serial2.read());  
  }
}
```

On Monitor, I received nothing: [Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnW4H.png)

## What I tested

- I connected the two ESP32 Rx and Tx Serial2 Pins with each other and the monitor prints AT AT AT ...  (so this works)
- I connected the ESP32 with the BC805M not by crossing Tx and Rx but like: Rx->Rx, Tx->Tx; I received the message

> BlueNor 200622 started

on my monitor. This means I read the values of the Rx pin of the BC805M and wrote them to my monitor. Shouldn't this message be sent on on the Tx pin of the BC805M?

- I connected to the BC805M per Android App, which connects to it via Bluetooth Low Energy. I sent commands from the app to the BC805M. But I got no response. I could read the commands I sent on the Rx Pin of the BC805M.
- I connected solely the BC805M per usb to my mac and ran Arduino-IDE's monitor, the monitor prints absolutely nothing and writing AT-Commands also results into nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fanstel support just wrote me that the BC805M Evaluation Board is **NOT** preloaded with the AT-Command firmware.

Only the BC805M module has it preloaded.

That explains why the AT-Commands did not work.